# Convergence in distribution for changing domains.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, conditional-probability, weak-convergence

I am trying to consider whether this is possible and/or reasonable:

Let $X_n:\Delta_n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of random variables, defined over a unique space $\Delta_n \subseteq \Omega$ for each $n$. The $\Delta_n \to \Delta$ in some sense of convergence of metric spaces. Is it reasonable to consider whether the $X_n$ converge in distribution to some $X:\Delta \to \mathbb{R}$?

I haven't found this described in this way anywhere but it seems like a reasonable idea to me (surely I haven't just made it up?!) as convergence in distribution should be convergence of the distribution functions $F_n (t) = \mu_n \{ \omega \in \Delta_n | X_n(\omega ) < t \}$ where $\mu_n$ is the conditional probability measure associated to $\Delta_n$.

If yes then can anybody point to anywhere that might help me calculate the distribution of $X$ for some particular examples I have, or anywhere that might talk about this idea and provide any theorems giving properties as I am struggling to get my head around it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence in distribution refers to a (well defined) convergence *of the distributions*, that is, of some probability measures defined on the target space. Thus the target space must be fixed (in your case, this seems to be the real line for every $n$ hence everything is fine) but the source spaces are simply irrelevant.